# Handlebars.js rendering different partials on different pages

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

So, I have two `{{header}}`s that I want to render on different pages. For home page, I want to use `{{home-header}}` for other pages, I want to use `{{header}}`. `base.hbs` is the main page where I call `{{header}}` and other partials. I just tried the following code, it didn't seem working. Tried to find an answer on handlebar.js documentation, no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{{#if home/main}}
  {{> home-header}}
{{else}}
  {{> header}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: And how exactly do you call handlebars?
Sounds like you need a loop were you call handlebars with different options.
And what's base.hbs?

Comment: The code above if that works. `base.hbs` is the main page where all partials get rendered on that page.

Comment: To what value are you expecting `home/main` to evaluate?